# Azure WebJob wrong platform target

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, platform, webjob

I have an Azure WebJob that I am publishing to an App Service.  The problem I am having is that I want to target the x86 platform but when I publish the WebJob and attach to the App Service, it's always listed as x64.

I set the platform target to x86 for all of my solution configurations.  There is only one solution platform.  I even have `RuntimeIdentifier` in the publish scipt set to "win7-x86".  I have no idea what I could possibly be missing.

The App Service is set to run on a 32-bit platform in the Application Settings.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the default worker process for your web app is `32-bit`. In order to check the current environment of your web app, you could leverage [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/).

For platform 32-bit:

[image]

For platform 64-bit:

[image]

Details you could access `https://{your-app-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml`.

For your webjob, you could use the Process explorer as follows:

For platform 32-bit:

[image]

For platform 64-bit:

[image]

In general, I would recommend you delete your existing webjob and redeploy it, then use the kudu to check the environment to narrow this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct approach to find out the Webjob process bitness from the Azure Portal or KUDU console. To determine it, you would need to collect the memory dump manually from the KUDU and this blogs covers it http://jsandersblog.azurewebsites.net/2017/02/02/how-to-get-a-full-memory-dump-in-azure-app-services/

Once the memory dump is collected for the Webjob process, you would need to open it in Windbg and run the following command:

Here is the command to check the process bitness:

```
0:000> !peb
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
WEBSITE_COMPUTE_MODE=Dedicated
WEBSITE_SKU=PremiumV2

0:000> .effmach
Effective machine: x86 compatible (x86)
```

Alternatively, you can open (just drag and drop) the dump in the Visual studio to see this information:

[image]

So, Webjob was concluded to be running as x86 bit.

In my case I wanted to run it x64 bit ness and this WebJob was deployed via VSTS built pipeline and missing the Platform argument. After setting that up to x64 the Webjob now runs x64 bit successfully.

[image]